# Issues with adding new line to text file

Tags: file, io, f#

I am trying to add new record to a text file inside a folder that is inside my console application.

```
open System.IO

let name = "Fred Thompson" 

let addLine (name: string) =
    use wr = StreamWriter("c:\\tempsource\\test.txt")
    wr.WriteLine(name)
    wr.Close
```

When I run in the interactive window, I get this:
warning FS0760: It is recommended that objects supporting the IDisposable interface are created using the syntax 'new Type(args)', rather than 'Type(args)' or 'Type' as a function value representing the constructor, to indicate that resources may be owned by the generated value.

Additionally, getting a blue squiggly line under the file--i shortened it for the example. I get the blue line with the full path as well.

Looking up this warning gave me this [Update warning message when creating IDisposable without 'new'](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/commit/70ed65d0f389ea84c3adba372c3a441934ed8288) and I have not a clue on have to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: just say ' new StreamWriter'

Comment: Thanks blue squiggly line is gone. But when I run it in the interactive window, the string does not get entered into the test.txt file.

Comment: are you appending? maybe add ,true after the path. then run addline "fred Thompson"

Comment: Adding a new record. not appending

Comment: With the use statement you don't need to close the writer. Auto close when out of scope. Hence the warning.

Comment: how are you executing this? can you show me the commandline?

Comment: you need to say wr.Close() or you could omit it as in Funk's comment.

Comment: You can close and dispose of resources simply by using a use binding
instead of a let binding, if the resource implements IDisposable.

Comment: Added the () to close. Still nothing going in to the text file? commandline??? I am hitting Run

Comment: oh, the function works. are you hitting run on this line: `addLine "blahblah"` because in the above snippet you just define the function, not actually running it.

Comment: I am totally confused now.

Comment: about what? are you actually running `addLine name`?

Comment: i am running the whole code.

Comment: you should run it like this, see the last line: https://gist.github.com/s952163/34181c600d7a4bf7b6f81682b3239876

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115597/discussion-between-s952163-and-aaron-m).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StreamWriter` constructor taking only a path creates a stream that overwrites the file. Passing `true` allows to append:

```
open System.IO

let name = "Fred Thompson" 

let addLine (name: string) =
    use wr = new StreamWriter("c:\\tempsource\\test.txt", true)
    wr.WriteLine name

addLine name
```

Comment: I would advocate taking the `Close` call (which needs parens BTW) out of your answer altogether, since it is strictly _un_-necessary.

Comment: @CaringDev thanks it works within interactive window; now if I run it through the Start button I get this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'c:\\users\\tempsource\test.txt' is denied.

Comment: @AaronM : If that's an actual copy&paste then you're missing a backslash before 'test'.

Comment: @ildjarn @AaronM Thanks, I removed the `Close` and replaced my homedir path with your original one.